# Clean way to return array indices matching a condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return all of the indices from an array where a condition is met. I've come up with

```
myarray
   .Select((p,i) => 
       {              
          if (SomeCondition(p)) return i; 
          else return -1;
       })
   .Where(p => p != -1);
```

I know I can write an extension method or do it with a loop, but I was wondering if there was something built into LINQ that I'm unfamiliar with. Apologies if this is trivial

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with this:

```
myarray
    .Select((p, i) => new { Item = p, Index = i })
    .Where(p => SomeCondition(p.Item))
    .Select(p => p.Index);
```

Comment: I came up with the same code. But I do not like that 'myarray' is traversed 3 times.

Comment: @hIpPy, this does not in fact traverse the array 3 times.  You should investigate the implementation of `.Select` and `.Where` a bit more.  Some operators *do* traverse the whole sequence (for example, `.OrderBy`), but ones that can be coalesced (like projections and filters) are more efficient than you're intuiting.

Comment: i see a `foreach` in `Select` and `Where` extension methods. how does it not traverse 3 times?

Answer (score 5):

When I read the text of the question and not the sample:

```
int[] data = { 1, 2, 5, 6, };

var results = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Where(i => data[i] > 2);

// results = { 2, 3 }
```

Do you really need those `-1`s ?

Comment: No, I don't need them at all, I just needed something to filter on in my query after the select since that just projects. Very clever solution btw

Comment: Personally I prefer Kirk's solution - why restrict yourself to arrays when you can have a solution which works over any sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write an extension method, but if I chose not to, I would do this:

```
array
  .Select((item, index) => SomeCondition(item) ? index : -1)
  .Where(index => index != -1);
```

It's exactly what you are doing already, but less verbose since it uses the ternary if operator instead of the `if`/`else` block.